# verify existence of a file that starts with a name chosen in a folder. (PHP)

Tags: php, file

I have a folder called `myfiles` ( `c/myfiles`), and I want to verify if within this folder is contained a file that begins with the name `filesearch_`.

**In C: directory I have:**

```
files.txt
filesearch_232142.xls  //TRUE in this case
filesearch_12.pdf   //TRUE in this case
fdsf.php
```

Searching `filesearch_` the result should be `true`. If not, it should be `false`. I have researched `glob`, but do not understand how to put a `glob` pattern function.

Comment: Do you have any code you tried out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use PHP ReadDir to see if a file exists:

```
<?php
$dir = "c:/myfiles";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      if (substr($file,0,11) == "filesearch_") {
         // file exists
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, how I can remove the file name containing the word I'm looking for?

Comment: use:  unlink($file);